# Why do you use "=+" in a Excel cell, when you can just use "="?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I want cell B4 = cell F4.

In B4 I go "=F4"

Why do people go "=+F4"

Both work, but what is the point?

Thanks

EDIT: i.e. this screenshot of a problem i'm working on: [image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case it's just convenience. It's much faster to type `+` rather than `=`, at least in a Spanish keyboard, and *Excel* will understand in both cases that you are editing a formula.

When you use `+` *Excel* will automatically convert it to `=+`once it validates the expression.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make any difference. Actually its an old lotus compatibility thing. Formulas previously were written by starting with '+' sign, so it came from there but it doesn't make any difference if you write '=' or '=+'

Comment: But there has to be a reason...look at the screenshot i just posted in the question. Cell F24 and G24 =+ , not sure why

Comment: @CescSergey:- As I said, this was used previously since all the formulas which were written were starting from + but it doesn't make any difference. It was for lotus compatibility and for some it was a matter of convenience(*See InBetween answer*)

Comment: Okay, maybe you are right, but a textbook written in 2014 is using =+. I dont think they care about lotus compatibility...But maybe to validate the expression as InBetween said?

Comment: @CescSergey:- Probably yes but since it was not making any difference thats why it was not changed and kept as is :)

Comment: @pnuts - Can you explain how the `(+F4` makes a difference when compared to `(F4`?

Comment: See Tom Urtis' reply [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/369789-why-do-some-people-use-plus-sign-beginning-formulas.html), basically makes the point with Lotus.

Answer (score 0):

The plus in front is simply *unary plus*. It's precisely the same concept as a minus in front is the *unary minus* (i.e. `=-F4` or `=F5+-F6`).

If you want to see it in even more action try writing a formula like `=A2++A3`.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) for more detail.

Comment: First of all I haven't down voted. Second, I *do* understand a downvote because your answer does not address at all what the OP is asking about. He's not asking what the unary `+` operator is, he seems to be very well aware of its "use". He's asking why it is used many times in excel formulas when it is clear it serves no purpose; `=+A3`